# SQL tricky left join of three tables - all different keys

Tags: sql, left-join

Originally I've been trying to merge `users_role_change_log` table with `users_schedule_log`. In the first I've got only user id, and in second there is only full name. So no clear hit.

I've tried to introduce third table which could tie those two together - `users` table. There is users id, but full name is splitted in two columns first_name and second_name. So that further complicates things. Not my design.

Was hoping that I could improvise in concating ad hoc first_name and last_name from main `users` table and passing it as a relevant parameter for left join.

```
SELECT r.*,CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) AS u.name 
FROM `users_role_change_log` r 
LEFT JOIN users u ON r.id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN users_schedule_log e ON u.name = e.name
```

But this doesn't work.

Any recommendation?

Edit:
#1 added table examples:
a) users_role_change_log

```
id user_id role time_changed
34   60      19  '2020-07-05 05:30:00'
```

b) users_schedule_log

```
id name       shift_start           shift_end
9  'John Doe' '2020-07-05 07:00:00' '2020-07-05 15:00:00'
```

c) users

```
id first_name last_name
60 'John'        'Doe'
```

d)what I want to end up with

```
a)user_id   b)name      a)role a)time_changed b)shift_start b)shift_end
60         'John Doe'    19    ...
```

Comment: Could you provide mock data along with the result you want to produce? In the query, you are not defining the table where first and last name exist.

Comment: in the edit, at d) is the end result which is aimed for

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must start the joins from `users` and the left join `users_role_change_log` and `users_schedule_log` on the correct columns:

```
SELECT u.id, CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) name, 
       r.role, r.time_changed, s.shift_start, s.shift_end 
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN users_role_change_log r ON r.user_id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN users_schedule_log s ON s.name = CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name)
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4V1cGZqgApxXZFSkVCCSbg/0).

Answer (score 0):

You could try it this way:

```
SELECT *
FROM `users_role_change_log` r 
LEFT JOIN users u ON r.id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN users_schedule_log e ON CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) = e.name
```

or this way:

```
WITH user_connector as (select CONCAT(first_name, ' ', last_name) as name, id from users)
SELECT *
FROM `users_role_change_log` r 
LEFT JOIN user_connector u ON r.id = u.id 
LEFT JOIN users_schedule_log e ON u.name = e.name
```

Of course you shoud change the asterisk to the fields you want to select.

Comment: that first solution is by far the simplest. and it works. thanks!

Comment: @hmmm___--_--___not_sure both solutions are wrong. You can't join users_role_change_log to users on their ids because they are not related. Did you try this code?

Comment: it's got small syntax error, should be user_id instead id, but overall logic is on point. thanks for mentioning that, completly forgot to add that detail

Comment: @hmmm___--_--___not_sure this is not a syntax error. Syntax errors throw errors. You accepted an answer that is wrong. Why?

Comment: it was first most simplistic and although not correct it was most helpful because I could work from there to version which works. regarding error all I've got from table were null values.

Comment: @hmmm___--_--___not_sure Didn't you get other answers that are correct?

Comment: Most helpful post was this because it forced me to tinker check everything and get correct result, but to be fair towards others I'll put first correct example as accepted. I'm new to stack, so I apologize for poor practice of priorities. I'll make sure in the future to learn from this example! Thanks for making me think about consideration for other people effort (which actually work).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the subquery for this. Hope to help, my friend :))

```
create table users_role(id int, user_id int, role int, time_changed datetime)
create table users_schedule(id int, name varchar(20), shift_start datetime, shift_end datetime)
create table users(id int, first_name varchar(20), last_name varchar(20))

insert into users_role
values(34, 60, 19, '2020-07-05 05:30:00')

insert into users_schedule
values(9, 'John Doe', '2020-07-05 07:00:00', '2020-07-05 15:00:00')

insert into users
values(60, 'John', 'Doe')

-----
Select *
FROM (SELECT r.*, CONCAT(u.first_name, ' ', u.last_name) AS Name 
FROM users_role r 
LEFT JOIN users u ON r.user_id = u.id )as t
LEFT JOIN users_schedule e ON t.Name = e.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer in this [fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mcz7UZ9Qdvuheee7nYqiaj/0). You need to construct a subquery for your users table where you `CONCAT` the columns and then proceed with the `JOIN`.

You might need to consider the database schema, since the table `users_schedule_log` can use the ID of the user rather than his name (same name problem).

```
SELECT r.user_id,  u.name, r.role, r.time_Changed, u.shift_start, u.shift_end
FROM users_role_change_log AS r
LEFT JOIN (SELECT id, CONCAT(first_name,' ',last_name) AS name FROM users)A 
ON r.user_id = A.id
LEFT JOIN users_schedule_log AS u
ON u.name = A.name
```